# Linear algebra span

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have some questions about span from practice questions for my linear algebra course. They are true/false.

1. If $0$ is in $\operatorname{span}\{\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2\}$, then $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$ are linearly dependent (unsure)
2. If $\operatorname{span}\{\vec{u},\vec{v}\} = \operatorname{span}\{\vec{u}\}$, then $\vec{v}=\vec{0}$.

I am unsure about question 1, but I believe question 2 is false since $\vec{v}$ could be a "multiple" of $\vec{u}$ (linearly dependent on $\vec{u}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"1" is **false** since $0\cdot v_1+0 \cdot v_2=0$ is a valid linear combination for the span

"2" is **false** since $u$ and $v$ can be **multiple**

Answer (score 1):

The standard orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $e_1 = (1,0)$ and $e_2 = (0,1)$ gives actually 
$$(0,0) = 0(1,0)+0(0,1).$$
That means $(0,0)$ is in spanned by $e_1,e_2$. However, they are linearly independent.

About the second, you are right.